# haskell how to remove the start word from the expected output

Tags: haskell

Am trying to find all possible partitions of a string. For example if i use this single word "sun" ,

```
`the expected output should be [["su","n"],["s","un"],["s","u","n"]]`
```

but in my code the output contains the string where the user inputs and i dont want this

```
        // i dont want ["sun"] in the output 
my output : [["sun"],["su","n"],["s","un"],["s","u","n"]]
```

Is there any way in my code to stop the function of containing the whole word into the output ?
I was thinging  to push as input into the auxiliary function the lenght of all partions of the string  :
length (<function_name> w ) , where w is the string and  if the a counter where i will set be equal to
length (<function_name> w ) -1 , stop making partitions but i didnt work .

My code is :

```
partition :: String->[[String]]

partition w =  help_partition w 


help_partition :: String->[[String]]
help_partition [x] = [[[x]]]
help_partition (x:xs) =  [(x:head l):(tail l) | l<- help_partition xs] ++[[x]:l | l<- help_partition xs]
```

Comment: You should be able to do what you're currently doing, just filter out `["sun"]` at the end.

Comment: @MLavrentyev i dont know how that's why am asking here , can you help me ?

Comment: use the filter function

Comment: to be more specific, take a look at doing `filter (/= [w]) (help_partition w)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make your `partition` function just filter out `[w]` from the result of `help_partition`. In other words:

```hs
partition w = filter (/= [w]) (help_partition w)
```

Comment: I must not use functions from libraries or any other fixed function

Comment: @tsoki you should specify this in your original question. I'm also not sure what you mean by "fixed function". Note that `filter` is available without importing any other libraries

Answer (score 2):

The way your `help_partition` function works, it will always include the full string as the *first* element in the returned list, so you can use `tail` to skip it:

```
partition w = tail (help_partition w)
```

or even:

```
partition = tail . help_partition
```

This is a pretty common technique:  you'll often find yourself writing a recursive function that *almost* returns the list you want but includes an extra special case as the first or last element, and you can use either `tail` or `init` to drop those elements.